# How to use CheckBoxes filter in Google DataStudio?

Tags: checkbox, filter, looker-studio

In a Report in Google DataStudio, I have a CSV connector (for the moment).

I would like to use a check box to sort only lines who are under a value on a specific page.

**The Facts:** I have a field who are listed the time in seconds. I've make a simple filter

`Include |MyFieldinSeconds|<=|86400`

This way work.

But I whould like to add a checkbox for apply this field or not. For the viewer, this is the hard part. The checkboxes options are **"Source of Data"** and **"Control Field"**, only `booleen`.

I've try to solve this by the group selection, by the Filter group option with the filter without success.

Thank You
Nicolas